# Immediate display proper div among set of divs and loop again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a school project and I need your help. What I made is a infinite loop through set of divs. There are 3 divs and 3 links.
When I click on these links, there should immediately display proper div (and display all divs after that and loop again). The problem is when I clicked there is a delay, which I don't want...
Is it possible that div is snown immediately when I clicked on link? Is there any other easier/less complex way? Can you please change/add the code I need? Thank you in advance.

```
<ul id="cyclelist">
  <li><div>Div 1</div></li>
  <li><div>Div 2</div></li>
  <li><div>Div 3</div></li>
</ul>
</br></br>
<a href="#" class="className1">link1</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="className2">link2</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="className3">link3</a><br/>


var j=0;
function changeOnClick()
{

$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('className1')) {
        j=-1;
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('className2')) {
        j=0;
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('className3')) {
        j=1;
    }
});
}

 var delay = 2000;
 function cycle(){
        var jmax = $("ul#cyclelist li").length -1;
        changeOnClick();
         $("ul#cyclelist li:eq(" + j + ")")
                 .animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,400)
                 .animate({"opacity" : "1"}, delay)
                 .animate({"opacity" : "0"}, 400, function(){
                         (j == jmax) ? j=0 : j++;
                         cycle();
                 });
         };
 cycle();
```

Comment: Do you know what does the second parameter of the function `.animate()`?

Comment: It'a delay - after 2 seconds it shows next div. I want this to stay as it is. I just don't want it on click on link - to display div immediately (without delay)...and than loop normally again (with delay). if you know any solution, please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
.animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,400)
```

the second parameter of the animation represents speed, thats why you are getting delay remove that

this is the syntax of .animate

```
$(selector).animate({params},speed,callback);
```

once go through it ..http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

**edit-**
so for your comment..i dont know weather its the correct way..better to call the cycle() using setTimeout();

```
setTimeout(cycle,2000);
```

Comment: I want this delay stay as it is.  I just don't want it on click on link - to display div immediately (without delay)...and than loop normally again (with delay).

Answer (score 0):

Try call cycle function from the event handler.
Something like this

```
if ($(this).hasClass('className1')) {
    j=-1;
    cycle();
}
```

This should resolve your problem.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Shouldn't I stop cycle() function before?

Comment: You can stop it if you want, yes. just store a reference to the element being animated, and then call stop or jumptoend method. See this: http://api.jquery.com/stop/